# Trouble installing QtCreator on CentOS

Tags: centos, qt-creator, glibc, installation

I downloaded the linux 64-bit .run from here, I'm running 64-bit CentOS: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

I followed the instructions by `chmod u+x [filename.run]`

I ran it `./QtSdk....`

I got these errors (below). I tried finding those libraries and installing them with 'yum.' Yum told me I was up-to-date with all those packages. What am I doing wrong?

```
./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run
./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by ./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run)
./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by ./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run)
./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by ./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run)
./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.10' not found (required by ./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run)
./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by ./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run)
./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by ./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the qt source package and build it yourself on CentOs.

Or you can upgrade the glibc to 2.12 (not recommend since it is require you upgrade lots of dependence libs.)